# JavaWebStart app randomly fails

Tags: java, jar, java-web-start

I have a JAR signed with a self-signed certificate and deployed by JWS.
It usually runs ok (most of the times) but sometimes fails which is quite annoying, It shows the splashscreen but nothing else.

These are the last log lines:

```
<record>
<date>2009-09-08T16:55:33</date>
<millis>1252421733468</millis>
<sequence>173</sequence>
<logger>com.sun.deploy</logger>
<level>FINE</level>
<class>com.sun.deploy.util.LoggerTraceListener</class>
<method>print</method>
<thread>10</thread>
<message>network: Conectando socket://127.0.0.1:4590 con proxy=DIRECT
</message>
</record>
<record>
<date>2009-09-08T16:55:37</date>
<millis>1252421737171</millis>
<sequence>174</sequence>
<logger>com.sun.deploy</logger>
<level>FINE</level>
<class>com.sun.deploy.util.LoggerTraceListener</class>
<method>print</method>
<thread>10</thread>
<message>security: JAVAWS AppPolicy Permission requested for: http://127.0.0.1/ikuspro/ikuspro.jar
</message>
</record>
<record>
<date>2009-09-08T16:55:37</date>
<millis>1252421737171</millis>
<sequence>175</sequence>
<logger>com.sun.deploy</logger>
<level>FINE</level>
<class>com.sun.deploy.util.LoggerTraceListener</class>
<method>print</method>
<thread>10</thread>
<message>security: We were not granted permission, exiting
</message>
</record>
</log>
```

And this is my jnlp file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Fichero JNLP de Ikuspro -->
<jnlp spec="6.0" codebase="http://127.0.0.1/ikuspro" href="ikuspro.jnlp">
<information>
<title>Ikuspro</title>
<vendor>MyName</vendor>
<homepage href=""/>
<description>Ikuspro</description>
<description kind="short">Desc+
</description>
<icon href="ikusproLogo.png"/>
<icon kind="splash" href="splash.png"/>
<offline-allowed/>
<shortcut online="true">
<desktop/>
<menu submenu="Ikuspro"/>
</shortcut>
</information>
<security>
<all-permissions/>
</security>
<update check="timeout" policy="prompt-update">
</update>
<resources>
<j2se version="1.6" java-vm-args="-esa -Xnoclassgc"/>
<jar href="ikuspro.jar"/>
</resources>
<application-desc main-class="ikuspro.main.Ikuspro"/>
</jnlp>
```

As I've said It doesn't always happen and the certificate has been accepted permanently.
Besides I see that the debugging is in FINE level, How can I make it more verbose?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like It was a bug in runtime 1.6.0_11. I have updated to 1.6.0_15 and It's working fine by now.